# A ㅜ that looks like a ㄱ, a bit confusing, is this common?

Tags: hangul

It took me a long time to figure out the first syllable is actually 우, for me it looked like ㅁㄱ although that would not be a real syllable, and neither would be ㅇㄱ.
It's not ambiguous but still confusing, are there more of these stylizations of hangul that are confusing for newbies?

[image]

Comment: Google 한글 서예 (서예 means calligraphy) and 손글씨 (handwriting) to see how they write Korean letters. On YouTube, you can find videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61DLZCv3bBw).

Comment: One trick to beginning to recognize these is to try writing Korean semi-cursively. The up-down strokes that make up ㅜ can easily start to look like ㄱ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's more:

1. Analogously, ㅗ might look like ㄴ.
2. ㅔ might look like 기. Some might even write ㅓ like ㄱ.
3. ㅐ might look like ɥ(Latin "h", rotated). ㄴ for ㅏ as well.
4. ㄷ might look like Japanese て.
5. ㄹ might look like Latin "z".
6. ㅁ might look like "12".
7. ㅂ might look like Latin "Id". That's where the famous ["IdH"](https://www.google.com/search?q=idH+korean&newwindow=1&hl=ko&sxsrf=ALeKk03r6UjogCfUA4cMnMkKgBCA2NKnVg:1621077941467&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEser2ycvwAhWkIaYKHb-JD1IQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1170&bih=694) comes from.
8. ㅌ might look like ㄷ with an overline.

[image: a]

I just brought a random picture from the results on Google when I searched for "글씨체 엉망"("handwriting terrible"). Apologies for the one who wrote this, but I feel like this explains most of the things you might want to be aware of.

Comment: You can see most of the strokes joined in the image.